# tweepy unbound method_call error

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

i'm trying to use tweepy for a simple request to get information about a particular user screen name. I did this:

```
import tweepy
api = tweepy.API
api.get_user('name')
```

I get the error:

```
unbound method _call() must be called with API instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of the API:

```
api = tweepy.API()
api.get_user('name')
```

A demo is always more instructive:

```
>>> import tweepy
>>> api = tweepy.API()
>>> api.get_user('zopatista')
<tweepy.models.User object at 0x10ffcd910>
```